# How to run multiple tests in Cypress without closing browser?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a 3 spec files for testing form filling and photo uploading using cypress.

1. spec file: Fill a form
2. spec file: Upload a photo
3. spec file: Check the results

Form is - https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

Problem is when fill a form test passes, browser is closed and 2 other test fail because I don't call open url in each test case.

If I run tests in GUI, everything is fine. Browser is not closed after first test, but when I run

`npx cypress run --headed --browser chrome`

from command line, problem occures.

I want to run tests from command line so browser doesn't close till all tests are finished.

Comment: Please add the code from your spec files in the question.

Comment: Code is irrelevant. When I run tests with cypress gui tests are performed one by one and browser is not closing.

Comment: I put test cases order in cypress.json

`"testFiles": [
        "Form.spec.js",
        "UploadFile.spec.js",
        "Check.spec.js"
    ]`

Form spec fill the form with user data, uploadfile spec upload a file on the same form and click submit, and check spec checks is file uploaded after test case step before submited filled form.

Problem is when I start all from command line. After first test case is over, browser is closed and second test case starts without browser and test case fails.

Comment: Did you tried the option --no-exit

Comment: Yes and after first test browser stays open but second test case doesn't start.

Comment: Exactly the same problem I am facing, when trying the npx cypress open, it works perfectly since all tests are ran consecutively, while trying npx cypress run --headed, just first test succeeds and the rest fail since they depend on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got exactly same problem and after hours of research I found a workaround that solves this. It is not a real fix but it solves your issue and mine.
Here are the steps I did:

Create a 4th spec file, call it main.spec.ts, inside this file do an import for the 3 spec files you have:

```
import './fillform.spec.js'
import './uploadphoto.spec.js'
import './result.spec.js'
```

In cypress.json file, add the following entry to allow to run only the main spec file:

```
"testFiles": ["main.spec.js"],
```

Now cypress run will work exactly as cypress open and all specs will run without closing the browser in between:

```
npx cypress run --headed --browser chrome
```